# Multiple custom JComponents, only one displayed

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

I am trying to make a custom JComponent that can be reused over and over in my program. I have set up a simple test of what I need to do, but I can't even get that to work.

```
class MyComponent extends JComponent {
    private String string = "";
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public MyComponent(String string, int x, int y){
        this.string = string;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString(string, x, y);
    }

}

public class GObject {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame Window = new JFrame();
        Window.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
        Window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        MyComponent com1 = new MyComponent("test123", 100, 100);
        MyComponent com2 = new MyComponent("test456", 20, 20);
        Window.add(com1);
        Window.add(com2);

        Window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Technically what I have created is a JLabel that can be positioned anywhere. You would expect to see two string displayed, "test123" and "test456", at those coordinates. However I only see the last string displayed.

[image]

[JFrame with only one string of text displayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hWaH.png)

**EDIT:**

Let me upload my actual code. I tried to simplify things by dumbing down my actual code.

Here is what I have:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class HeatG2 {
    public static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

    public static void main(String[] args){
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Sheet sheet = new Sheet();
        frame.add(sheet);
        frame.setSize(1000, 800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Sheet extends JPanel{
    public Heat test1;
    public Heat test2;

    public Sheet(){
        test1 = new Heat();
        test1.setPosition(10, 10);
        test1.setHeat(1);
        test1.setHeight(150);
        add(test1);

        test2 = new Heat();
        test2.setPosition(10, 310);
        test2.setHeat(2);
        test2.setHeight(150);
        add(test2);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Heat extends JComponent{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int height;
    private int heat;
    private String driver1 = "";
    private String driver2 = "";

    public String getDriver1(){
        return driver1;
    }

    public String getDriver2(){
        return driver2;
    }

    public void setDriver1(String driver1){
        this.driver1 = driver1;
        System.out.println(this.driver1);
    }

    public void setDriver2(String driver2){
        this.driver2 = driver2;
        System.out.println(this.driver2);
    }

    public void setPosition(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height){
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void setHeat(int heat){
        this.heat = heat;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString(driver1, x, y);
        g.drawLine(x, y, x+250, y);
        g.drawLine(x+250, y, x+250, y+height);
        g.drawString(driver2, x, y+height);
        g.drawLine(x, y+height, x+250, y+height);
    }
}
```

Multiple heats need to be added at specified locations on a sheet (JPanel). The Jpanel will then be added to the JWindow.

**EDIT 2:**

I ended up fixing this issue by not extending component. I used the class as a template for a paintable object instead.

Comment: Please follow [Code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), your variable names should be lower case. And btw don't ever call a class Window (not this case, but your variable name is "Window") you could have some problems with [Window class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to use absolute positioning because the components will eventually be added to a scroll pane

Scrolling does not work with absolute positing because the scroll pane and its related scrollbars will only work when the preferred size of the panel is greater than the size of the scroll pane. If you don't use a layout manager then you need to manage the preferred size yourself.

You need to use something like the [Drag Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/) which will manage the preferred size of your panel for you.

> Technically what I have created is a JLabel that can be positioned anywhere.

Then technically you should be using a JLabel so you don't reinvent the wheel. Your concept of how components work is wrong. Components have a `size` and a `location`. So the custom painting will paint the text relative to (0, 0) of the component. Then you use the `setLocation(...)` method to position the component in the parent panel.

If you want to do custom painting then you are responsible for determining the preferred size of each component and the size will vary based on the text you specify as a parameter so you need to use `FontMetrics`. This is another reason to just use a JLable.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand now. See the edit in my original post to clear some things up. @camickr

Answer (score 4):

You need to check the layout. If it is BorderLayout(Default) it will show only the last one try to use different layout. Something like GridLayout or FlowLayout

Comment: If I need stuff to be positioned at specific coordinates, should I set the layout manager to null?

Comment: You can set to null layout if you window will not get resized. Generally we dont you null layout.

Comment: I need to use absolute positioning because the components will eventually be added to a scroll pane. If the user resizes the window, they will just need to scroll. Most of the content will be "offscreen" already.

Comment: What you mean with `they will just need to scroll` and `Most of the content will be "offscreen"`?

Comment: @Aaron If you are going to do your own drawing, it is usually easier to have a single JComponent that will handle all the drawing to coordinate locations. You can then have it deal with a list of Custom objects that will hold coordinates and Strings or Images to draw at those coordiantes. Then in your JComponent you override getPreferredSize to maintain the right graphics area. Put it in a JScrollPane for scrolling automatically.

Comment: Yes you can use as per your design requirement. But check what is  contentPane default layout.

Comment: @Frakcool There will be components placed at say 3000, 1000. The user already knows they will scroll to see the rest of the data.